# smtp codeigniter gmail error

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, gmail

I am sorry I keep coming back with this issue. I checked my account and it’s fine( signed on no captcha) and still nothing. It still returns this to me:

220 mx.google.com ESMTP d13sm702743fka.52

hello: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [82.128.53.160]
250-SIZE 35651584
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 PIPELINING
Failed to authenticate password. Error: 454 4.7.0 Cannot authenticate due to temporary system problem. Try again later. d13sm702743fka.52

from: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 d13sm702743fka.52
The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.

i saw a post somewhere in my googling that php mail() does not do smtp with google mail well, is that true? if so I looked at the wiki on phpmailer and swiftmailer and the writeup is scanty, so any ideas on what to do? possibly with links or tips…. ANYTHING PLEASE!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need SMTP auth with TLS, [here is a forum post](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84689/P0/) describing how to do it in CI.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! It was this line `$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");` that was stopping my mail from sending.

Comment: how did you fix it? I have that line and is not sending, I tried without it and still not sending, any idea??

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of checking,  it seems that the email class of codeigniter is kinda ify with gmails smtp. so I looked for other alternatives and found phpmailer and I have mail working with my app. Anyone looking to use mail in codeigniter app should consider using the phpmailer plugin. Much easier than email lib.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i've solved it enabling pop on gmail.

In Gmail: configuration -> pop/imap -> enable pop

And then "Allowing less secure apps to access your account". When i allow that everythig started working.

Here is a link where i found the info: [Support google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: `$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.